# I try to write code for linked lists in C

Tags: c, list, function, insert, nodes

I must write a code for a lab and i don't understand how i can insert the nodes with which function.

struct list
{int value;
struct list * next;};

int main()........
the code says that we ask the user how many integers (N) he wants to insert to the list.. so easy printf, scanf
AND THEN ..It will ask for the numbers and list them in the order they are given.
I think that i need a for loop
but i know many function for inserting for example insertAfter, push etc, etc
I need you help! Thank you

Comment: First, the structure you defined is not a list.  It's just the components of 1 node of a list. So, perhaps calling it "list" is misleading. Second, since you defined a pointer as a second member, I understand that you already studied how to allocate elements dinamically. You need that: when asking for the numbers, you will build your list node by node, allocating them.  And then, you will traverse the entire chain of elements (the list of nodes you created) and show the numbers.

Comment: thank you for your help! yep it is not a list :).

Comment: In fact, you don't "insert" nodes. You tell one node which is the next node in the chain (through the `next` data member).  But I see somebody already gave you a full answer, without explanation... (* sigh *)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure you have given represents a **node**. You first create a **head** of the list, then you need to read numbers one by one, create a node for each number and append it at the end of the list using `append()` function defined in the code given below.

Here is the full program you require (function codes taken from geeksforgeeks.org):

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 

// A linked list node 
struct Node 
{ 
  int data; 
  struct Node *next; 
}; 

/* Given a reference (pointer to pointer) to the head 
   of a list and an int, appends a new node at the end  */
void append(struct Node** head_ref, int new_data) 
{ 
    /* 1. allocate node */
    struct Node* new_node = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node)); 

    struct Node *last = *head_ref;  /* used in step 5*/

    /* 2. put in the data  */
    new_node->data  = new_data; 

    /* 3. This new node is going to be the last node, so make next of 
          it as NULL*/
    new_node->next = NULL; 

    /* 4. If the Linked List is empty, then make the new node as head */
    if (*head_ref == NULL) 
    { 
       *head_ref = new_node; 
       return; 
    } 

    /* 5. Else traverse till the last node */
    while (last->next != NULL) 
        last = last->next; 

    /* 6. Change the next of last node */
    last->next = new_node; 
    return; 
} 


// This function prints contents of linked list starting from head 
void printList(struct Node *node) 
{ 
  while (node != NULL) 
  { 
     printf(" %d ", node->data); 
     node = node->next; 
  } 
} 


int main() 
{ 
  /* Start with the empty list */
  struct Node* head = NULL; 

  int n;
  scanf("%d", &n);

  for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    int e;
    scanf("%d", &e);
    append(&head, e);
  }

  printList(head);
}
```

Comment: you help is so important to me!!
have a nice day!!

Comment: how i can upvote you answer?
i am here first time and i do not know many things!!

Comment: The top-left of the answer where it shows '-1' (it represents number of votes given to this answer). There are up and down arrows above and below that. You just need to click the 'up' arrow to upvote an answer.